# How small can velcro be?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, material-science, physical-chemistry, estimation

**Note:** "fiber" refers to individual hooks and/or loops.

---

Imagine two flawless graphene sheets, one with atomic diameter hydrocarbon loops attached to one face, one with atomic diameter hydrocarbon hooks (chains) attached to one face. We push the two sheets together, and they stick to one another, then we pull them apart. We then repeat the process, but this time they come apart more easily. After the $n^\text{th}$ time doing this, the sheets stop adhering altogether. We put the sheets under our magical microscope to see what's wrong, and find that all of the fibers we so carefully attached to the sheets have twisted and broken and turned into methane, CO<sub>2</sub>, and chicken wire.

This is because when placed close enough together the fibers interact (with each other and the air), forming new chemical bonds which may also break when we pull the sheets apart, leaving a more stable structure behind. The more times we do this, the more messed up our fibers get, until they stop being hooks and loops altogether and instead settle in the most stable configuration the system can take (I'm not a chemist, but I'm absolutely certain that "molecular velcro" is not the ground state for this system).

Clearly, we can't make Atomic Velcro (TM)...

Or maybe we can?

If you ever look at filamentous algae under a microscope, you may notice that it sometimes gets tangled into a microscopic spaghetti ball. Likewise, bacterial flagella can *probably* become tangled together (whether or not this actually happens is a matter of ongoing debate), so the fibers can *probably* be at least as small as 10 nm across. Even if there are interactions like those described above, maybe everything stays "just classical enough" at the atomic scale to still count as velcro? Probably not, but I don't actually know!

**How small** ***can*** **we make velcro**?

And how do we arrive at our best guess? There are several things to consider:

- **Mechanical vs intermolecular forces/chemical interaction:** At some point, intermolecular forces overtake mechanical ones. That is, beyond some lower bound on the diameter of the fibers, forces between the constituent molecules become more significant to the overall behaviour of the system than the mechanical forces (e.g. friction, tension, etc.) acting on the fibers.
- **Classical vs quantum effects:** At some point, quantum effects overtake classical ones, and we need to account for the nonclassical behaviour of the fibers. In particular, a sufficiently small hook is liable to pass through a sufficiently small loop "because quantum."
- **Statistical behaviour:** While fibers almost certainly deform past their elastic limit from time to time, this happens infrequently enough in macroscopic velcro that adhesion is reliably maintained for a period of time greater than or equal to that required for the material to degrade through other means (i.e. chemical, biological, dog hair clinging to your jacket no matter how many times you clean it). To make microscopic velcro, the time required for all of the fibers to degrade should not exceed the time it takes for at least one fiber in every hook-loop pair to undergo mechanical failure.

(also, at some point the interaction between fibers may become insignificant compared to the forces between the surfaces to which the fibers are attached)

---

**Note:** Because this question concerns the boundary of classical and quantum mechanics (and statistical mechanics... and continuum mechanics) I'm not sure how best to tag it. If anyone has more appropriate tags, feel free to edit!

Comment: Legally, we can't create velcro of any size, ony hook and loop! The question could be focused more and made more about physics as opposed to materials engineering by clearly defining the hypothetical product and then asking be what its properties are. "How could we make it" is an engineering problem.

Comment: @gs The question isn't about the means by which such a hook and loop fastener would be made, but giving an estimate on the theoretical lower limit to the diameter of the fibers used to make it. The problem is with creating a reasonable model, not interpreting an existing one. If we were working purely with molecular dynamics, I'd know what to do. If we were working with macroscopic fasteners, I'd know what to do. Somewhere between 0.3 nm and 3 μm, something happens and I don't know what to do anymore. That's what the question is about.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_machine

Comment: At nanoscale you don't need any hooks, though. Two graphene layers stick perfectly with vdW interactions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_setae

Comment: @Mithoron The point isn't to make a useful adhesive, but to guess the scale at which vdW, etc. overtake mechanical interactions altogether while focusing the question enough that an answer is possible. This is an instance of the more general problem of the classical/quantuum barrier.